# Update one table when joined to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

Difficult to describe in one sentence.  In the database I have a table that is split across 2 tables because the column sizes exceed the servers maximum.  The 2 tables are joined by a unique id.  There is a guid in the first table that identifies the row.  Like so:

```
Table_1
AGUID   Join_Key    Other columns ...
aabbcc 1         ...
ddeeff 2         ...

Table_2
Join_Key    Field_To_Update   Other different columns ...
1                               ...
2                               ...
```

I have the GUID and a string to go in Field_To_Update.

```
update table_2 set Field_To_Update = 'the new column value'
where
  table_2.Join_Key = table_1.Join_Key and
  table_1.AGUID = 'aabbcc'
```

Is this the correct approach?

In the real database the table names are ridiculously long - can aliasing be used?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, so quickly. I was pretty close, couldn't figure the join.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you need a `from` clause:

```
update t2
    set Field_To_Update = 'the new column value'
    from table_2 t2 join
         table_1 t1
         on t2.Join_Key = t1.Join_Key and
    where t1.AGUID = 'aabbcc';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use join with update

```
Update a 
   SET a.Field_To_Update = 'the new column'
from table_2 a 
   JOIN Table_1 b
on a.Join_key = b.Join_key
where b.AGUID = 'aabbcc'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to your problem

```
update b set Field_To_Update = 'the new column value'
from table_1 as a 
inner join table_2 as b on a.Join_Key = b.Join_Key
where
  a.AGUID = 'aabbcc'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update t2
set Field_To_Update = 'column Name'
from table_2 t2 
INNER JOIN table_1 t1 on t2.Join_Key = t1.Join_Key
where t1.AGUID = 'aabbcc';
```